# osmNX in Google Colab

Tags: osmnx

For my purposes I require osmNX in Google Colab

Has anyone done this before? I use the following commands:

```
!wget https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2019.07-Linux-x86_64.sh && bash Anaconda3-2019.07-Linux-x86_64.sh -bfp /usr/local

import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages')

!conda config --prepend channels conda-forge
```

The command:

```
!conda info --envs
```

Shows that the enviroment is created succesfully.

When I run the command:

```
!conda activate ox
```

The error is displayed:

```
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run
    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>
Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell
See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.
IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.
```

The command

```
!conda init bash
```

has no effect.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

!apt-get -qq install -y libspatialindex-dev && pip install -q -U osmnx
import osmnx as ox
ox.config(use_cache=True, log_console=True)

you can use this command !

Answer (score 2):

```
!pip install geopandas== 0.10.0
!pip install matplotlib==3.4
!pip install networkx==2.6
!pip install numpy==1.21
!pip install pandas==1.3
!pip install pyproj==3.2
!pip install requests==2.26
!pip install Rtree==0.9
!pip install Shapely==1.7
!pip install osmnx
```

I installed the respective packages based on the requirements provided in this link https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/blob/main/requirements.txt , it has worked in my application so far, hope it works for you too.

Alternatively, similar to another answer, you can use the code below, found in https://stackoverflow.com/a/65378540/18403512:

```
!apt install libspatialindex-dev
!pip install osmnx
```

Answer (score -1):

The answer would be similar to running `osmnx` on any docker or external server.
I tried it and almost got there, maybe someone can help make it complete.

So let's start with the basic `osmnx` installation:

```
conda config --prepend channels conda-forge
conda create -n ox --strict-channel-priority osmnx
```

Then, let's look at how can this be done at remote docker, e.g. travis CI (working sample `.travis.yml` from one of my repos):

```
 - bash miniconda.sh -b -p $HOME/miniconda
 - source "$HOME/miniconda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
 - hash -r
 - conda config --set always_yes yes --set changeps1 no
 - conda update -q conda
 # Useful for debugging any issues with conda
 - conda info -a
 - conda config --prepend channels conda-forge
 - conda create -n ox --strict-channel-priority osmnx
 - conda activate ox
```

Then we may take a look at how to have conda in [colab](https://towardsdatascience.com/conda-google-colab-75f7c867a522) and use this snippet:

```
%%bash
MINICONDA_INSTALLER_SCRIPT=Miniconda3-4.5.4-Linux-x86_64.sh
MINICONDA_PREFIX=/usr/local
wget https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/$MINICONDA_INSTALLER_SCRIPT
chmod +x $MINICONDA_INSTALLER_SCRIPT
./$MINICONDA_INSTALLER_SCRIPT -b -f -p $MINICONDA_PREFIX
```

which then finally boils down to [this](https://github.com/RafalKucharskiPK/ExMAS/blob/dev/ExMAS/spinoffs/colab.ipynb) almost working notebook, based on [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/75948/how-to-setup-and-run-conda-on-google-colab) post.

What is not working is switching between environments, so `!conda env list` returns `ox` as one of environments, yet activating it fails:

```
!conda activate ox
```

raises:

```
    CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.
```