# import osmnx on google colab give me an error

Tags: python, osmnx, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to import `osmnx` on google Colab and it did install successfully using `!pip install osmnx` but when I try to import it in Colab like this `import osmnx` give me this error

```
AttributeError: /usr/bin/python3: undefined symbol: Error_GetLastErrorNum
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install libspatialindex-dev first.

```
!apt install libspatialindex-dev
!pip install osmnx
```

Then you can import it

```
import osmnx
```